# Why would proxies fail in Scrapy, but make succesful requests under the python-requests library

Tags: python, proxy, scrapy, python-requests, request

I have a list of say 100 proxies, and to test them I make a request to google and check the response.
When running these requests through python-requests, every request returns successfully, but when attempting the same thing under Scrapy, 99% of the time the proxies fail.  Am I missing something or using the proxies wrong in Scrapy?

The proxies are stored in a file in the format

```
http://123.123.123.123:8080
https://234.234.234.234:8080
http://321.321.321.321:8080
...
```

Here's the script I was using to test them with python-requests

```
import requests

proxyPool = []
with open("proxy_pool.txt", "r") as f:
    proxyPool = f.readlines()

proxyPool = [x.strip() for x in proxyPool]

for proxyItem in proxyPool:
    # Strip the http/s from the ip
    proxy = proxyItem.rsplit("/")[-1].split(":")
    proxy = "{proxy}:{port}".format(proxy=proxy[0], port=proxy[1])
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36", }

    proxySession = requests.Session()
    proxySession.proxies = {"http://": proxy, "https://": proxy}
    proxySession.headers.update(headers)
    resp = proxySession.get("https://www.google.com/")

    if resp.status_code == 200:
        print(f"Requests with proxies: {proxySession.proxies} - Successful")
    else:
        print(f"Requests with proxies: {proxySession.proxies} - Unsuccessful")
    time.sleep(3)
```

and the spider for Scrapy

```
class ProxySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "proxyspider"

    start_urls = ["https://www.google.com/"]

    def start_requests(self):
        with open("proxy_pool.txt", "r") as f:
            for proxy in f.readlines():
                proxy = proxy.strip()
                headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36", }

                yield Request(url=self.start_urls[0], callback=self.parse, headers=headers, meta={"proxy": proxy}, dont_filter=True)

    def parse(self, response):
        self.logger.info(f'Parsing: {response.url}')
        if response.status == 200:
            print(f"Requests with proxies: {response.meta['proxy']} - Successful")
        else:
            print(f"Requests with proxies: {response.meta['proxy']} - Unsuccessful")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your code sample built with `requests` - You implemented multiple sessions (1 session - 1 proxy).

However on scrapy default settings - application will use single `cookiejar` for all proxies.
It will send the same cookie data for each proxy.
You need to use [`cookiejar` meta key](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#std-reqmeta-cookiejar) in your requests

If webserver receive requests from multiple IPs with single `sessionId` transferred in cookieheaders - it looks suspicious and webserver is able identify it as bot and ban all used IPs. - probably exact this thing happened.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, it appears to have drastically improved the amount of succesful requests!
I am still receiving more unsuccessful attempts when compared to using just the requests library though.  Do you know of any other things that may be worth playing around with to try and increase the amount of successful requests when using scrapy?

Comment: second major difference between your `requests` and `scrapy` code samples - delays between requests. On `requests` you used `time.sleep`. On scrapy it is required to set `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` setting.